# Xsd minOccurs and maxOccurs as database relationship translation

Tags: xml, database, xsd

I am building simple algorithm that migrates xsd schema to database.

Now I am wondering how to decode how minOccurs and maxOccurs attributes from xsd schema translates to database relationship.

With simple example complex type:

```
<xs:complexType name="contents">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
        <xs:extension base="content">
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="colA" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="refContentA" />
                <xs:element name="colB" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="ContentB" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="refContentCB" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:all>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Correct me if I am wrong, so for my understanding:

- `<xs:complexType name="contents">` is table with columns colA, colB
- `<xs:element name="colA" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="refContentA" />` is a relationship to table refContantA with relationship 1 .. 1
- `<xs:element name="colB" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">` is reference to table colB with column ContentB (but can't decode relationship is it one to one or one to many)

Now am I interpreting this as database right?

If I build DB schema on my description I would be able to export data (using of course mapping) that will fit that schema?

Comment: You're scratching at the surface of a very deep problem. In general, translations from one data model to another are imperfect. To do them well you need to understand the semantics of the data, not just its structural constraints. You say you want a "simple algorithm", but what does that mean? That it's OK if it only does a good job 80% of the time? Which 80%?

Comment: Well I know there is a large abstraction layer beetwen xsd and actual database schema and becouse of that I know I would need to bend that to use it as database schema. But am I interpreting that xsd schema right.

Comment: You may or may not be interpreting it correctly. You don't know, for example, whether the order of elements in XML is significant and needs to be preserved in the relational database. You haven't said anything about sequence and choice and how they interact with minOccurs and maxOccurs. Without a much more complete description of your algorithm, and how it handles arbitrarily complex model groups, it's impossible to say.

Comment: Also for your colB understanding, don't you mean maxOccurs="unbounded" as per your XSD?  That means there is a 1 to many relationship